# Adding a remote pointing to a local git repo appears to fail

Tags: git

I'm following this SO article to migrate a local branch in one repo to a local branch in a new repo (we migrated from github to gitlab).

[How to merge branches in 2 different repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468700/how-to-merge-branches-in-2-different-repositories)

I encountered a problem along the way. I added a remote pointing to the old github local repo:

```
git remote add github-local ~/myprojectdir/src/.git
```

When I run `git branch -r` in the newly cloned gitlab repo, I expected to see branches from both `github-local` (the remote I just added above), and from `origin`. But I only see branches from origin.

The next step in the SO article above is to create a branch and track `github-local/mybranch`:

```
git checkout -b mybranch --track github-local/mybranch
```

I assume I can't do that if I don't see it in the list of remotes when I run `git branch -r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your remote shows up in remotes list. Run `git remote -v`. The output should be similar to:

```
github-local ~/myprojectdir/src/.git (fetch)
github-local ~/myprojectdir/src/.git (push)
origin       repo_url (fetch)
origin       repo_url (push)
```

If `github-local` shows up in remote list, you are simply missing `git fetch --all`.

After that you should be able to track branches from `github-local` as you posted in question. Run:

```
git checkout -b mybranch --track github-local/mybranch
```

Then verify everything is as you expect by running `git branch -vv`. The output should be similar to:

```
mybranch 068512a [github-local/mybranch] commit_message
```

Comment: `git fetch -all`, that was it. Brilliant. Thanks! Makes lots of sense in hindsight.